# 8-10" Retaining wall on bottom of fence

Tags: walls, fence

I'm looking to replace a shared fence with a neighbor and his ground level is around 6-8" higher than ours. A section of the current fence has a retaining wall (or I guess also called a kick board) at the bottom that varies in height of 6-10".

I'd like to replace the original fence posts with Postmaster steel posts but my question is whether I can attach a 2x8 or 2x10 pressure treated (for ground contact) board at the bottom? Should the posts be moved closer together (6 ft. instead of 8 ft.? Ours vary now from 5 to 7 ft).

I'm trying to find whether a span of 6 ft. if the steel posts with 2x8 will support the load of the neighbor's ground, or if I'll need additonal 4x4 support posts.

Also, with a retaining wall like this that is shorter than 1 ft., would I need to do anything with drainage? Also, same question if I went with a stacked block wall. Thanks!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. This is an interesting question, but a bit broad for our site. It's best if you only ask a single question per actual question. And, more info would be helpful: soil type? length of fence? your location?

Comment: I think dry stack blocks of the heavier size (30 lb or so) make a much better low retaining wall than PT wood, and should be easier. A 1 ft high wood retaining wall would require short 4x4s every 2 ft.